# Problems with pythonanywhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I made a bot for discord on python.when I ran it on the computer via the command line, everything worked. But then I switched to pythonanywhere and this error comes out:

```
2023-01-28 16:11:21 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 535, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('162.159.128.233', 443)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/Kaktus/Kaktus3.1.py", line 314, in <module>
    Bot.run('ODU0Njg2NDQwNzg0NTI3MzYw.GEMHj4.KEGWAAyfp9kbMw5II0ilC-wm8sJHOj4GzrpSzo')
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 624, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 536, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/ZakaryZak/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('162.159.128.233', 443)]
```

my code

```
import datetime
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import json
import os

intents = discord.Intents.all()
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
Bot.remove_command('help')


@Bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот запущен')

@Bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.send('''Hi, I'm a Kaktus! You won't forget your homework with me anymore :chocolate_bar:
    !nhw - if you want to pin a homework (New Home Work)
    !wm_YourClass - if you want to see the pinned homework (Wate Make)

    ex:
    !wm_GA
    !wm_GD
    !wm_GP


    If the bot does not work, write to support

    Technical support:  Yana
    :mushroom: :mushroom: :mushroom:
    ONLY for support:
    !text - получить текст файла, прости не разобралась как отправить сам фаил
    ВСЕ С МАЛЕНЬКОЙ БУКВЫ
    v 2.2''')


@Bot.command()
@commands.has_role(1068913422944714812)
async def nhw(ctx):
    # если не удается считать базу (файл не найден или еще какая-то проблема)
    # то будет создаваться новая, пустая база
    try:
        with open('Kaktus.txt','r') as f:
            baza = json.load(f)
    except:
        baza = {}


    # функция, возвращающая сообщение, ожидаемое из wait_for
        def check(message):
        # если автор ожидаемого сообщения - автор команды nhw, то это сообщение можно принять
        # проверка нужна, чтобы другие пользователи не мешали выполнению команды своими сообщениями
            if message.author == ctx.author:
                return message
    u = 1
    while u == 1:
        await ctx.send('Class (GA,GD or GP)')
        await ctx.send('ex: GA,GP')
        clas_message = await Bot.wait_for('message')

        await ctx.send('Lesson?')
        lesson_message = await Bot.wait_for('message')

        await ctx.send('What make?')
        what_make_message = await Bot.wait_for('message')

        await ctx.send('Where to send?')
        drive_message = await Bot.wait_for('message')

        await ctx.send('Deadline? (dd/mm/yyyy)')
        deadline_message = await Bot.wait_for('message')

        emb = discord.Embed(title=lesson_message.content, color=0xFFF0)
        emb.add_field(name= 'Class :',value=clas_message.content,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name= 'You mast',value=what_make_message.content,inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=drive_message.content, inline=False)
        emb.add_field(name= 'Dedline',value=deadline_message.content,inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed = emb)
        await ctx.send("It's good? (y/n)")
        w = await Bot.wait_for('message')
        w = w.content.lower()

        if w == 'y' :

            x = '1'
            while x in baza:
                a = int (x)
                a = a+1
                x = str(a)

            baza[x] = {
                'Class':clas_message.content,
                'Lesn':lesson_message.content,
                'You mast': what_make_message.content,
                'Send to:': drive_message.content,
                'Dedline': deadline_message.content
            }

            u = 0
            await ctx.send('homework saved')

        if w == 'n':
            await ctx.send("well, let's change it")

        if (w != 'n') and (w != 'y'):
            await ctx.send("error: i dont understend you")

    with open('Kaktus.txt','w') as f:
        # чтобы вместо '\u0435' и т.п. писались кириллические симолы
        # можно указать параметр ensure_ascii=False

        # для удобного чтения файла можно добавить параметр отступов
        # indent=4 (где 4 - количество пробелов)
        json.dump(baza, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

@Bot.command()
async def wm_GA(ctx):
    try:
        with open('Kaktus.txt','r') as f:
            baza = json.load(f)
    except:
        baza = {}

    coll = 0
    x = '1'
    while x in baza:

        lesn = baza[x]['Lesn']
        clas = baza[x]['Class']
        home = baza[x]['You mast']
        Mto = baza[x]['Send to:']
        date = baza[x]['Dedline']
        ddl = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        naw = datetime.date.today()

        if 'A' in clas:
            coll = coll + 1

            if ddl == naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(dititle=lesn, color=0x0000FF)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name= 'You mast',value=home,inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name= 'Dedline: :name_badge::name_badge::name_badge:',value=date,inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send( embed = emb)

            if ddl < naw:
                del baza[x]

                z = x
                y = int(x) #4
                x = int(x) + 1 #5
                while x in baza:
                    baza[y]=baza[x] # b4 =b5
                    y = int(x)   #5
                    x = str(x+1) #6
                x = z

            if ddl > naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(title=lesn, color=0xFFF0)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name= 'You mast',value=home,inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name= 'Dedline',value=date,inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send( embed = emb)


        a = int (x)
        a = a+1
        x = str(a)

    if coll == 0:
        await ctx.author.send(':sauropod: :sauropod: :sauropod: Don\'t have home work!))):pizza: :pizza: :pizza:')

    with open('Kaktus.txt','w') as f:
        json.dump(baza,f)

@Bot.command()
async def wm_GD(ctx):
    try:
        with open('Kaktus.txt', 'r') as f:
            baza = json.load(f)
    except:
        baza = {}

    coll = 0
    x = '1'
    while x in baza:

        lesn = baza[x]['Lesn']
        clas = baza[x]['Class']
        home = baza[x]['You mast']
        Mto = baza[x]['Send to:']
        date = baza[x]['Dedline']
        ddl = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        naw = datetime.date.today()

        if 'D' in clas:
            coll = coll + 1

            if ddl == naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(dititle=lesn, color=0x0000FF)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='You mast', value=home, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Dedline: :name_badge::name_badge::name_badge:', value=date, inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)

            if ddl < naw:
                del baza[x]

                z = x
                y = int(x)  # 4
                x = int(x) + 1  # 5
                while x in baza:
                    baza[y] = baza[x]  # b4 =b5
                    y = int(x)  # 5
                    x = str(x + 1)  # 6
                x = z

            if ddl > naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(title=lesn, color=0xFFF0)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='You mast', value=home, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Dedline', value=date, inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)

        a = int(x)
        a = a + 1
        x = str(a)

    if coll == 0:
        await ctx.author.send(':sauropod: :sauropod: :sauropod: Don\'t have home work!))):pizza: :pizza: :pizza:')

    with open('Kaktus.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(baza, f)

@Bot.command()
async def wm_GP(ctx):
    try:
        with open('Kaktus.txt', 'r') as f:
            baza = json.load(f)
    except:
        baza = {}

    coll = 0
    x = '1'
    while x in baza:

        lesn = baza[x]['Lesn']
        clas = baza[x]['Class']
        home = baza[x]['You mast']
        Mto = baza[x]['Send to:']
        date = baza[x]['Dedline']
        ddl = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
        naw = datetime.date.today()

        if 'P' in clas:

            coll = coll + 1

            if ddl == naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(dititle=lesn, color=0x0000FF)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='You mast', value=home, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Dedline: :name_badge::name_badge::name_badge:', value=date, inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)

            if ddl < naw:
                del baza[x]

                z = x
                y = int(x)  # 4
                x = int(x) + 1  # 5
                while x in baza:
                    baza[y] = baza[x]  # b4 =b5
                    y = int(x)  # 5
                    x = str(x + 1)  # 6
                x = z

            if ddl > naw:
                emb = discord.Embed(title=lesn, color=0xFFF0)
                emb.add_field(name='Class :', value=clas, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='You mast', value=home, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Send to:', value=Mto, inline=False)
                emb.add_field(name='Dedline', value=date, inline=False)
                await ctx.author.send(embed=emb)

        a = int(x)
        a = a + 1
        x = str(a)

    if coll == 0:
        await ctx.author.send(':sauropod: :sauropod: :sauropod: Don\'t have home work!))):pizza: :pizza: :pizza: ')

    with open('Kaktus.txt', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(baza, f)

@Bot.command()
async def text(ctx):
    try:
        with open('Kaktus.txt', 'r') as fp:
            await ctx.author.send(fp.read())
    except:
        await ctx.author.send('файл не найден или не создан')

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I have already reinstalled the discord library, recreated the token, nothing helps
please help as I wrote it for the class to remove problems with homework. I'm not a programmer, but an artist, so please, without toxicity, I'm doing everything in my power

I googled the error. causes of occurrence, solutions. I opened the library documentation on PyPI, read the discord update. they advised reinstalling the library or updating the token, but nothing worked, otherwise there was no information (or it's time for me to change glasses))

Comment: Per the linked duplicate, you need a paid PythonAnywhere account to connect to discord.